# Flex collision testing with hitTestObject

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to test clipping on two canvases. Both canvases are 100px wide. They're 20px apart. I've placed a label inside one and made it 200px wide. Scroll bars will show up on the canvas. When I don't have the label inside and use hitTestObject it returns false. When I place the label inside it returns true. Is there any way to alter the canvas with the label inside so that it doesn't expand to the width of the label?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        private function init() : void {
            var hitBox:Sprite = new Sprite;
            hitBox.graphics.drawRect(box1.x, box1.y, 100, 100);

            box1.hitArea = hitBox;
            box1.mouseEnabled = false;

            trace('box hit area: ' + box1.getBounds(box1));
            trace('hitbox: ' + hitBox);
            trace('box hit test: ' + box1.hitTestObject(box2));
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Canvas id="box1" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
    <mx:Label text="This is a test" width="200" />
</mx:Canvas>
<mx:Canvas id="box2" x="120" y="10" width="100" height="100" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can accomplish what you want with `hitTestObject`. I played around with setting the `clipContent` and `horizontalScrollPolicy` properties on your canvases, to no use. What I think is happening is that `hitTestObject` considers your canvas to be as wide as the longest child component, regardless of any clip masks or scroll bars.

Are you forced to use `hitTestObject`? If not, I'd suggest writing your own collision detection function along the lines of:

```
public static function componentsCollide( obj1:DisplayObject, obj2:DisplayObject ):Boolean {
    var bounds1:Rectangle = new Rectangle( obj1.x, obj1.y, obj1.width, obj1.height );
    var bounds2:Rectangle = new Rectangle( obj2.x, obj2.y, obj2.width, obj2.height );

    return bounds1.intersects( bounds2 );
}
```

Comment: I tried playing around with some other methods but nothing seemed to work. This is a simple replacement that works perfect. Thanks for your help.