# How can I test if a Flex control is obscured by another?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to write a function

```
internal function isObscured(o: DisplayObject): Boolean;
```

which tells whether the given object `o` is partially or completely obscured by another object. I already tried using [`hitTestObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29) and [`hitTestPoint`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29); the latter would actually do what I want if I tested *every* point in the bounding rectangle of the object at hand - not very efficient. I also tried using [`setChildIndex`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29) but it doesn't seem to help either since it's possible that an object isn't obscured even though it does not have the largest child index.

My current approach is to test whether any bounding rectangle of the objects with larger child indices than the object at hand intersects with the bounding rectangle of the object at hand, however I suspect that this will only work for testing whether any *sibling* overlaps my object.

Does anybody know whether there's a better way to check whether a Flex control is obscured by another?

Answer (score 1):

You must retrieve the rectangle that represent each of the components and test them.

It is well explained here: [Flex collision testing with hitTestObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276108/flex-collision-testing-with-hittestobject)

HIH

Comment: The `components` would be those which have a larger child index than the object at hand? It seemed to me that the child index is per-parent, not per Stage.

Comment: you should use the depth property of the object instead. This question is related to such issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276108/flex-collision-testing-with-hittestobject

Comment: Ah, interesting - I wasn't aware of [`depth`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#depth)! Unfortunately it seems that this is only used to define the order in which children of a given object are rendered - however, the `depth` value is not applicable on a "global" level it seems. So I *think* you can have two objects `o { depth: 1 }` and `p { depth: 2 }` and `o` hsa two children with depth  1 and 2 even if `p` has two objects with depth 1 and 2 as well. Does that sound right?

Comment: I think yes but I am not sure of how this mixture of depth, childs, ... is actually working. It's quiet hard to find information about the z-index or the display order in flex.